# I don't know how to apply async/await concept

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the function below:

```
    let updateDevicesStatus = async () => {
       getAllConnectedClients()
       let teste = getAllDevices()

       try {
          devicesDB = await teste
       } catch (e) {
          console.log('deu erro')
       }
       devicesDB.forEach( (currentDevice) => {
          connectedClients.forEach( (currentClient) => {
             if (arduinoNM.connected[currentClient].clientID == currentDevice.clientID) {
                devicesOnline.push(currentDevice)
             } else {
                devicesOffline.push(currentDevice)
             }
          })
       })
}
```

`getAllDevices()` retrieve some data on DB, therefore, it takes more time to execute.

Node.JS run all these calls asynchronously, what causes an exception, saying that devicesDB is undefined.

I tried to use async/await to make `updateDevicesStatus()` wait for `getAllDevices()` execution, but it's not happening...

What I'm doing wrong?

`getAllDevices()` is not declared with async. Should I do it?

**EDIT:**

getAllDevicesPromise() function:

```
function getAllDevicesPromise() {
            return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                resolve(getAllDevices())
            })
        }
```

getAllDevices() function:

```
function getAllDevices() {
            let rst
            let query = Arduino.where({})
            query.find( (err, results) => {
                if (err) return console.error('[ERR] Erro buscando todos os dispositivos do banco para WEB.')
                rst = results
            })
            return rst
        }
```

I'm testing these function as below:

```
let test = await getAllDevicesPromise()
console.log(test)
```

But it still returning undefined. There's something more that I need to do?

Comment: Probably getAllDevices does not return a Promise! It does not need to be async, but it needs to return a Promise in order for it to be awaited.

Comment: You're right, @LuanNico. I'll search how to return a promise in this function and test it again. Thanks so far!

Comment: Could you fix the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either :

use `async/await` which is a [Syntactic Sugar For Promises in Javascript](http://Async%20and%20Await:%20Syntactic%20Sugar%20For%20Promises%20in%20Javascript) , you'll need to promisify the `getAllDevices()` function to `resolve` with the result of the query, and then `await` for it in the `async updateDevicesStatus`

```
function getAllDevices() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let rst;
        let query = Arduino.where({});
        query.find((err, results) => {
          if (err) reject('[ERR] Erro buscando todos os dispositivos do banco para WEB.');

          resolve(results);
       });
    });
}

let updateDevicesStatus = async () => {
  getAllConnectedClients();

  let devicesDB = await getAllDevices();

  devicesDB.forEach((currentDevice) => {
    connectedClients.forEach((currentClient) => {
      if (arduinoNM.connected[currentClient].clientID == currentDevice.clientID) {
        devicesOnline.push(currentDevice);
      } else {
        devicesOffline.push(currentDevice);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

or use a callback :

```
function getAllDevices(cb) {
  let rst;
  let query = Arduino.where({});
  query.find((err, results) => {
    if (err) cb('[ERR] Erro buscando todos os dispositivos do banco para WEB.');

    cb(null, results);
  })
}

let updateDevicesStatus = () => {
  getAllConnectedClients()

  getAllDevices((err, devicesDB) => {
    if(err) // do something with the error

    devicesDB.forEach((currentDevice) => {
    connectedClients.forEach((currentClient) => {
      if (arduinoNM.connected[currentClient].clientID == currentDevice.clientID) {
        devicesOnline.push(currentDevice);
      } else {
        devicesOffline.push(currentDevice);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let teste = getAllDevices()
... 
devicesDB = await teste`

^^ This will not work as you expect because you are calling getAllDevices, assigning the return value to teste, and then waiting for nothing.

It should just be:

`let devicesDB = await getAllDevices();`

Comment: If `getAllDevices()` returns a promise then awaiting that promise with `await teste` is identical to `await getAllDevices()`. If `getAllDevices` doesn't return a promise, neither will work.